# What is a tabukuk?

Tags: languages, object-identification, terminology, a-plague-of-demons

Near the beginning of [Keith Laumer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keith_Laumer)'s *[A Plague of Demons](https://www.baen.com/Chapters/0743435885/0743435885.htm)*,* two spies are meeting in a restaurant in North Africa, and one sweeps their table for surveillance devices.

> We went through a ritual of hand pumping and when-did-I-see-you-last’s, ordered second drinks, then moved over to a low table.  He slipped a small gadget from a pocket, glanced around to see who was watching, then ran it over the light fixture, the salt and pepper shakers, the ashtray, babbling on:
>
> “Martha’s fine.  Little Herbie had a touch of Chinese virus, and Charlotte broke a clavicle....”  He went on point like a hunting dog, picked up a small *tabukuk* in the form of a frog-goddess, dropped it inconspicuously into his heavy briefcase.  [italics in original]

I wasn't familiar with the word "tabukuk" for the small item containing the listening device—and it appears that virtually nobody else is either.  The italics identify it as a foreign term, probably something that Laumer encountered when he worked as a Foreign Service officer; and, indeed, the *Oxford English Dictionary* knows nothing of the term.  However, the rest of the World-Wide Web appears to be equally ignorant of what the term means.  Searches for it turn up people and places with similar proper names (such as Tabuk, Saudi Arabia), along with references to Laumer's novel.  Whatever it refers to, "tabukuk" is probably not the normal spelling of the term in the Latin alphabet.

[Passing the question on](https://languagehat.com/stern-nincompoops/#comment-4350272) to folks who are often good about answering linguistic question has turned up some vague leads (such as some kind of drum), but nothing really definite.  Laumer is deceased, so there's no chance of e-mailing him about it.  So I'm asking here as well:  What is a tabukuk?

*Depending on what kind of device you are using, the above link to the Baen Books Web site may give you access to the entire book, or just a teaser; however the elements I'm asking about occurs on the very first page.

Comment: I became very excited at seeing a question involving the works of Keith Laumer. A lifelong fan of the man and his books.  Therefore, I am crushed that I have no answer to give.  Your investigation has been admirably thorough.  I think you're quite right that Laumer is giving his own spelling to something he encountered in his travels. I tried to imagine what might be on the table of a tourist trap Arabic cafe depicted in the story. Wild shot: an incense censer in Arabic areas is a "dabqaad".  Obviously, not the same spelling, but an interesting similarity in consonant sounds. A frog dabqadd?

Comment: @Blaze You may be on the right track. Myself I was thinking about a small Egyptian statue representing one of the many gods. I can't recall the exact name but it was something similar to tabukuk. Maybe a conflation of 2 names. There is also the Biblical name Habakuk (or Habukuk) who is one of the 12 minor prophets in the Old Testament.

Comment: @Blaze Would you consider making that an answer, even if it only a tentative one?  This sounds like the most promising explanation I have encountered so far.

Answer (score 2):

At the Original Poster's request, I'll reiterate my comment as a provisional "answer".

Buzz's search efforts were obviously and impressively thorough.  Any possible answer would require a more long-odds avenue of investigation.

Upon reading the passage in *Plague of Demons* (the greatest challenge by far was not being distracted into happily rereading the book for the umpteenth time), I tried to imagine the scene.  A tourist-trap of a faux Arabic cafe.  What would they have on their tables that would look like a little frog sculpture?

I offer a guess that it may be an incense censer.  In Arabic countries, such a censer is called a "dabqaad".  Obviously, not the same spelling as "tabukuk", but an interesting similarity in consonant sounds. A frog dabqadd?  As mentioned, Keith Laumer might easily have phonetically transcribed a word he heard in his travels.